# Correctly create a class with subclasses (C#)

Tags: c#, class

I am creating a program in C# and I don't know how to create my classes.
Here's what my class looks like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class Parameters
    {
        string Value { get; set;}
    }

    public class Methods
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Window.Title = Parameters.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I want to be able to use it from another class:

```
public class MainClass
{
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    myclass.Parameters.Value = "Hello World !";
    myclass.Methods.MyMethod();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timespan.FromSeconds(10));

    MyClass myclass2 = new MyClass();
    myclass2.Parameters.Value = "Hello World Again !";
    myclass2.Methods.MyMethod();

    //I know this code is stupid, it's just to simplify my example.
}
```

But it doesn't work, there are accessibility problems that I don't know how to solve.

Thanks in advance, I don't think that the solution is very complicated but I can't find it.

Comment: Those aren’t subclasses. Those are nested classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to make the `Value` property `public` to get or set it from outside the class:

```cs
public string Value { get; set; }
```

2. The classes are not `static`, so you need to instantiate them to set their properties or use their methods:

```cs
var parameters = new MyClass.Parameters();
parameters.Value = "Hello World !";
var methods = new MyClass.Methods();
methods.MyMethod();
```

3. The same applies here:

```cs
public void MyMethod()
{
    var parameters = new MyClass.Parameters();
    Window.Title = parameters.Value;
}
```

4. But I suspect you actually want `MyClass` to have its own instances of these classes. So you can add properties for them:

```cs
public Properties Properties { get; set; }

public Methods Methods { get; set; }
```

5. Then instantiate them somehow (like in the constructor):

```cs
public MyClass()
{
    Parameters = new Parameters();
    Methods = new Methods();
}
```

If you do steps 1, 4 and 5, the code you have in `MainClass` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the properties and methods all within the class:

```
public class MyClass
{

   public MyClass() 
   {
     // Set any initial values
   }

   public string Value { get; set;}
   public void MyMethod()
   {
      Window.Title = Value;
   }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
public class MainClass
{
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    myclass.Value = "Hello World !";
    myclass.MyMethod();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timespan.FromSeconds(10));

    MyClass myclass2 = new MyClass();
    myclass2.Value = "Hello World Again !";
    myclass2.MyMethod();
}
```

Or to be more succinct:

```
public class MainClass
{
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass {
       Value = "Hello World !"
    };
    myclass.MyMethod();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timespan.FromSeconds(10));

    MyClass myclass2 = new MyClass {
       Value = "Hello World Again !"
    };
    myclass2.MyMethod();
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you absolutely need the classes split (although I wouldn't recommend it), then you need to pass your value into the method class to use it. There are a couple of approaches. Either you have to pass the value down into you methods class (not a very elegant approach):

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Value { get; set;}

   public Methods methods {get; set;)

   public MyClass(string value) 
   {
     methods = new Methods(value);
     Value = value;
   }

   public class Methods 
   {
     public string Value { get; set;}

     public Methods(string value) 
     {
       Value=value;
     }

    public void MyMethod() 
    {
       Window.Title = Value;
    }
   }
}
```

Or make MyMethod() a static method and pass in the value to use:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Value { get; set;}

   public MyClass(string value) 
   {
     methods = new Methods(value);
     Value = value;
   }
}

public static class Methods 
{
  public static void MyMethod(string Value) 
  {
       Window.Title = Value;
  }
}
```

```
public class MainClass
{
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass {
       Value = "Hello World !"
    };
    Methods.MyMethod(myclass.Value);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timespan.FromSeconds(10));

    MyClass myclass2 = new MyClass {
       Value = "Hello World Again !"
    };
    Methods.MyMethod(myclass2.Value);
}
```

Both ways are not best practice though as, when you start building more complex classes, having the properties and methods in different places will cause a load of headaches.

Comment: I would like not to remove the nested classes because it allows my class to be better organized.
Unless there is a way to create categories without using a nested class.

Comment: just updated my answer. I wouldn't recommend doing it this way but if you must I have included the code

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor that force the user to add a Value when initiating the class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public MyClass(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }


    public class Methods
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Window.Title = Value;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
   MyClass myclass = new MyClass("Hello World !");
    myclass.Methods.MyMethod();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timespan.FromSeconds(10));

    MyClass myclass2 = new MyClass("Hello World Again !");
    myclass2.Methods.MyMethod();
```

Comment: I can't do like this because there will be a lot of parameters.